# Deploy MSI package from Sonatype Nexus using chef

Tags: chef-infra, nexus, nuget-package

I want to install the msi package from sonatype Nexus using Chef.
Here what I need to achieve is , If the new version of msi is arrived in nexus repository chef should take the latest and deploy it automatically.

Can you tell me how can I do it.

Thanks,
Ram

Comment: How are you storing the the MSI in nexus? Which repo type you are using?

Answer (score -1):

The smartass answer? Write some code to do that thing you said. You can find information about how to install an MSI with Chef in the docs, and as for Nexus either look for an existing community cookbook or write something yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have a recipe to install the msi package. Here the source will be in my local machine. it works fine . But my problem is how to take the package from Nexus and deploy it automatically using chef

Comment: Again, the way you do it is to write some code. Chef has no core support for Nexus beyond the standard `remote_file` resource which can download files via HTTP. If you need more than that, you need to write it.

Comment: Okay. I will write.

Here I need to acheive one more step. I want to deploy the msi package using Chef in daily basis. So I have configured node and it has the runlist . Can you tell me how can i do this.